# Count unique value of an object in array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to count the occurences of the field `uuid` in my collection. The dataset is a collection of Magic the Gathering decks. I want to see which cards are played the most. This is an example document in the collection:

```
_id:60aa430832f934a5874f7e3a
code:"JMP"
commander:Array
mainBoard:Array
name:"Rogues (1)"
releaseDate:"2020-07-17"
sideBoard:Array
type:"Jumpstart"
```

The uuid is located in a object in the `mainBoard` array. This would look like this:

```
mainBoard:Array[
{0:Object
artist:"Daarken"
...
uuid:"d99be31c-b176-530a-bb17-88056d2e06b1"}]
```

This is the aggregation I have tried without achieving my goal:

```
pipeline = [
    {'$project': {"mainBoard": 1}},
    {'$unwind': "$mainBoard"},
    {'$group': {'_id': '$uuid', "count": {'$sum': 1}}},
    {'$sort': {'_id': 1}},
]

# execute pipeline
for doc in database.deck_lists.aggregate(pipeline):
    pprint(doc)
```

The aggregation above returns: `{'_id': None, 'count': 22559}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "uuid" field is within the "mainBoard" object array.

Comment: so you did wrong in `$group` stage just use `{ "$group": { "_id": "$mainBoard.uuid"...`

Comment: I have adjusted it to `{ "$group": { "_id": "$mainBoard.uuid"...` . I am still getting the same return from the aggregation...

Comment: you are probably missing something other, after change query looks good see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a39bXZ7a840)

Comment: Oh god, All the time I had a typo in my aggregate... Thanks!